# Grid Layout "Linked Margins" change to "Different Margins" automatically

Tags: adobe-xd

I'm fighting with this the whole day and I can't seem to get it to have the same value for left-right margins.

Every time I change the value in "Linked margins" it switches to "Different margins" with different left and right values.

And what's even more interesting is that I can set the Linked margins to 100px but can't do the same for 101px or 101.5px (what I need).

I think it might happen because "Gutter width" option is never changing according to the margins I'm trying to setup (unlike Column width).

Screenshot of what happens when I setup 101px on Linked margins (XD switches to different margins by itself):

[image: Adobe XD grid layout margins]